# CORS preflight error redux & loopback API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, redux, loopbackjs

I have a client application on `react-redux` & API app on `loopback`.

For my local testing I am running client app on port 8080 and server app on port 3000.

When I try to test out the Google OAuth (using `loopback-passport component`) with the client app, I am getting the below error.

[image]

When I test it using POSTMAN, there are no issues.

Here is the client side code,

```
require('babel-polyfill'); 
import { CALL_API } from 'redux-api-middleware'; 
import C from '../constants';
const API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:3000';
function googleLogin() {   return async(dispatch) => {
    const actionResp = await dispatch({
      [CALL_API]: {
        endpoint: API_ROOT + '/auth/google',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': API_ROOT
        },
        method: 'GET',
        types: ['GET', 'GET_SUCCESS', 'GET_FAILED']
      }
    });

    if (actionResp.error) {
      console.log(actionResp);
      throw new Error('Some error in communication', actionResp);
    } else {
      console.log(actionResp);
    }   
 }; 
}
```

CORS settings in loopback middleware is as below,

```
"cors": {
   "params": {
      "origin": true,
      "credentials": false,
      "maxAge": 86400
    }
  }
```

This sounds like a simple problem, appreciate any help here.

Comment: Can you fork https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sandbox and create a sample project. I have configured our loopback project to work with CORS. I 'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

> Most browsers currently don’t support following redirects for preflighted requests.

try this in your case:

> 1. Make a simple request to determine (using Response.url for the Fetch API, or XHR.responseURL to determine what URL the real preflighted request would end up at).
> 2. Make another request (the “real” request) using the URL you obtained from Response.url or XMLHttpRequest.responseURL in the first step.

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) - Preflighted requests and redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests_and_redirects)